# Прокси с selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Всем здравствуйте!
Прошу помощи у опытных коллег. Делаю прогру для автоматизации регистрации аккаунтов. Застопорился на прокси. Не меняет ip. Использую мобильные прокси, всё грузится, но не меняется ip адрес. в чём может быть причина, и что я сделал не так?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
useragent = UserAgent()
    
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f"user-agent={useragent.random}")
    
p = 'kohteht:HQfFbSbzD7@46.8.31.218:43601'
options.add_argument(f"--proxy-server={p}")
    
url = "https://whoer.net/ru"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="Chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe",
                              options=options
                              )
    
 try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(5)
 except Exception as e:
      print(e)
 finally:
      driver.close()
      driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `selenium-wire`(`pip install selenium-wire`) с вашим прокси загрузка может быть долгой:

```py
import time

from seleniumwire import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

useragent = UserAgent()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f"user-agent={useragent.random}")

options_proxy = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': 'http://kohteht:HQfFbSbzD7@46.8.31.218:43601',
        'https': 'https://kohteht:HQfFbSbzD7@46.8.31.218:43601',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}


url = "https://whoer.net/ru"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="Chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe",
                          options=options, seleniumwire_options=options_proxy)

try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(25)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помоглорешить мой вопрос.